# The link provided by flutter has following 404 error when clicked

Tags: google-codelab

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R1sRaALXDyxnXzVO1zq-R5UFzSJEbsoh/view?usp=sharing

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1#4

The link provided by flutter has following 404 error when clicked

https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/master/startup_namer_null_safety/step3_stateful_widget/lib/main.dart

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L0NibqvLO3x6HMBjYZxgoEhZkfS01-bd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This has nothing to do with Flutter as that is a Google Codelabs. I'll suggest to use the contact section of that website to report that issue but StackOverFlow is not the place to do it.

Comment: Where is contact section of that website to report this issue?  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/

Comment: This has everything to do with Flutter for those developers trying to use their tutorials. I've already reported to github.   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86929

Comment: This falls under "off topics" for StackOverFlow as has nothing to do with coding... is just a missing file on a Codelabs. Again, StackOverFlow is not the site to report those things. Use the correct channels like Google Codelabs itself or the GitHub repository

Comment: Got response back from github.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/10IeJxhLv7CnILqHDrvIAEZUC_8z-H_mN/view?usp=sharing